# Fastest way to compare chars of 'A', 'C', 'G', 'T'

Tags: c++, performance, binary, char, bioinformatics

I'm hoping to boost the speed of my bioinformatics algorithm, which requires comparisons of characters that are one of 'A', 'C', 'G', 'T' (e.g. computing 'A' == 'C')

Since the size of a char is 8 bits, it requires 8 comparisons of binary numbers in worst case scenario. My guess was that, by representing 'A', 'C', 'G', 'T' as a pair of binary numbers  (e.g. 'A' as make_pair(false,false)), I thought I could possibly boost the speed by 3~4 times since it now only requires 2 binary comparisons at maximum.

I tried using a pair of bools, but speed actually dropped by about 30%.

What is the fastest possible way to represent the four characters and to compute equality? Memory usage isn't so much of a problem for my case.

For your information, I'm using C++11 compiler. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `Since the size of a char is 8 bits, it requires 8 comparisons of binary numbers in worst case scenario.` What? This is not how computers compare numbers.

Comment: Put your code into godbolt.org to see what's going on

Comment: Is SIMD allowed, and what kind? For example AVX2?

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact problem or error. A description alone is not enough. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The amount of bits that can be compared using a single instruction depends on your CPU architecture. A 64bit architecture means that you can run computations on a 64bit word in a single instruction, not 64 instructions. So comparing two 8bit words (`'A'=='G'`) takes exactly 1 CPU cycle to compute.

If you want to boost your speed, you can represent your characters in 2bit words, but pack 32 words in a 64bit variable, and run the comparisons 32 words at a time, thus reducing the amount of CPU cycles by a factor of 32.

Now, if you want to compare multiple 64bit variables that are stored sequentially in an array, you can make use of `memcmp` to allow the sequential scan to be optimized properly.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps starting over with different initial concepts...
I dug up an old note from helping someone learning this stuff about a decade ago. Maybe it can give you a helpfully different perspective.

https://gist.github.com/TomConlin/6cd976151d36dd3e2a9fb34842b9c66e